# Understanding numpy array shapes

Tags: python, numpy, conv-neural-network

I'm having a lot of problems to understand numpy array shape.

If have a numpy array with shape `(1, 12, 12, 512)`, does it means?

1. I have 512 arrays of shape `(1, 12, 12)`.
2. I have one array of shape `(12, 12, 512)`

What does it means?

By the way, this numpy array is a feature map from an encoder CNN model.

If I use [tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/GlobalAveragePooling2D) with that feature map, I get a Tensor with shape `(1, 512)` that is what it makes me doubt.

To show a simplest array and try to understand it, I have used this code:

```
x = tf.constant([[1., 2., 3.],
                 [4., 5., 6.]])
y = tf.reshape(x, [1, 2, 3, 1])
```

`x` array is:

```
array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [4., 5., 6.]], dtype=float32)
```

`y` array is:

```
array([[[[1.],
         [2.],
         [3.]],

        [[4.],
         [5.],
         [6.]]]], dtype=float32)
```

So I think is the second option, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both those two statements are correct. However, ultimately it comes down to what your data object represents. If the first axis is the batch, it's more likely to be `1` batch containing `512` `12x12`-feature maps.

---

*Edit*: Which is the case, since you mention Tensorflow. The library works this with format:
`(batch, height, width, channels)`. Where the channels are last, contrary to how PyTorch operates.

`tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D` will, for each batch, average each one of your `12x12` feature maps into a single point. Since you have 512 feature maps, this will leave you with a shape of `(1, 512)`. *"Global"* means it will average **the whole feature map**.

Comment: Yes, you are right, because the `output_channels` for the last Conv2D layer is 512, so I have 512 feature maps of size 12x12 but, if you check the code that I have added to my question, it seems that the second option is the right one. Maybe because I don't understand every thing completely. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: In your example, `y` is essentially a single batch of  `1` `2x3` feature map, and in this case would be the correct format. Glad I could help!